# Terminology for masculine vs. feminine speech/language styles

Tags: terminology, sociolinguistics

I'm looking for terminology to describe voices/speech/language patterns in a dataset in a publication based on whether they seem to the linguistically-educated transcriber to be "masculine", "feminine" or "other/both/neither/undecided". However, I'm **not** concerned with the actual gender of the participants, and I haven't got data on that anyway, so using the term *gender* seems misleading to me. Is there any common terminology which is used to capture this general categorization?

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate and, unfortunately, unanswered): https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25585/feminisation-of-mens-language

Comment: That question is only very tangentially related and IMHO is a bad question: This question is about a the perception of a specific group of phenomena (e.g. fundamental frequency, prosodic patterns, lexical choice) while the other one is extremely broad as well as vague.

Comment: Wouldn't the best way to go about this be to do a sort of pilot study that open-endedly asks individuals to describe the speech they're hearing? My guess is that using masculine or feminine would be the most intuitive to subjects, in any case. If you used some technical terms to avoid gendered terms, I'm not sure what the point would be: the subjects would probably be confused and you wouldn't be able to link the descriptions to any broader context. It would be like asking "does this sound flabitus or carpital?"

Comment: @joshisanonymous the intended terminology is for linguists, not experiment participants.

Comment: If I am understanding this question correctly, I'd say this is a question better suited for the cognitive sciences stack exchange.